# SQL-Server XML-Bulk-Import and reading as table-data

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have the following Problem:

For the XML-Import into SQL-Sever, I use this code:

```
DROP TABLE XMLwithOpenXML

CREATE TABLE XMLwithOpenXML
(
Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
XMLData XML,
LoadedDateTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO XMLwithOpenXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '\\WINSER1\\proALPHA\\templates_eBus\\Test.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML
```

It works fine. But here in the XML, I don't know, what should I do:

```
    <MIME_INFO>
        <MIME>
            <MIME_TYPE>image/jpeg</MIME_TYPE>
            <MIME_SOURCE>ube105252.jpg</MIME_SOURCE>
            <MIME_PURPOSE>normal</MIME_PURPOSE>
            <MIME_ORDER>1</MIME_ORDER>
        </MIME>
        <MIME>
            <MIME_TYPE>image/jpeg</MIME_TYPE>
            <MIME_SOURCE>bbd372670.jpg</MIME_SOURCE>
            <MIME_PURPOSE>logo</MIME_PURPOSE>
            <MIME_ORDER>2</MIME_ORDER>
        </MIME>
    </MIME_INFO>
```

An user of me, needs both `<MIME>-Blocks`. But they are named the same!

How can I get this 8 rows contented in the 2 `<Mime>-Tags`? Rename is not the solution, because the XML has over 2.000.000 rows!

THX.

EDIT 16:20
Here the rest of the code above. With this tags it works fine:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT  [SUPPLIER_AID]
       ,REFERENCE_FEATURE_SYSTEM_NAME
       ,REFERENCE_FEATURE_GROUP_ID


FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'BMECAT/T_NEW_CATALOG/ARTICLE')
--FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'BMECAT/T_NEW_CATALOG/ARTICLE/ARTICLE_ORDER_DETAILS')
--## Hier werden die gewünschten Columns deklariert.
WITH 
(
     SUPPLIER_AID [varchar](25) 'SUPPLIER_AID'
    ,REFERENCE_FEATURE_SYSTEM_NAME [varchar](25) 'REFERENCE_FEATURE_SYSTEM_NAME'
    ,REFERENCE_FEATURE_GROUP_ID [varchar](25) 'REFERENCE_FEATURE_GROUP_ID'

)
```

-----------------------------EDIT 16092016 / 08:14-----------------------------

I still don't understand your code, because you use not the real table "XMLwithOpenXML". Hier is one article of ~ 20.000 in the XML:

```
<BMECAT>
    <T_NEW_CATALOG>
        <ARTICLE mode="new">
            <SUPPLIER_AID>9900026005</SUPPLIER_AID>
            <MIME_INFO>
                <MIME>
                    <MIME_TYPE>image/jpeg</MIME_TYPE>
                    <MIME_SOURCE>ube105252.jpg</MIME_SOURCE>
                    <MIME_PURPOSE>normal</MIME_PURPOSE>
                    <MIME_ORDER>1</MIME_ORDER>
                </MIME>
                <MIME>
                    <MIME_TYPE>image/jpeg</MIME_TYPE>
                    <MIME_SOURCE>bbd372670.jpg</MIME_SOURCE>
                    <MIME_PURPOSE>logo</MIME_PURPOSE>
                    <MIME_ORDER>2</MIME_ORDER>
                </MIME>
                <MIME>
                    <MIME_TYPE>image/jpeg</MIME_TYPE>
                    <MIME_SOURCE>ube305149.jpg</MIME_SOURCE>
                    <MIME_PURPOSE>logo</MIME_PURPOSE>
                    <MIME_ORDER>3</MIME_ORDER>
                </MIME>
                <MIME>
                    <MIME_TYPE>image/jpeg</MIME_TYPE>
                    <MIME_SOURCE>ube108453.jpg</MIME_SOURCE>
                    <MIME_PURPOSE>others</MIME_PURPOSE>
                    <MIME_ORDER>4</MIME_ORDER>
                </MIME>
                <MIME>
                    <MIME_TYPE>application/pdf</MIME_TYPE>
                    <MIME_SOURCE>ube007100.pdf</MIME_SOURCE>
                    <MIME_PURPOSE>others</MIME_PURPOSE>
                    <MIME_ORDER>5</MIME_ORDER>
                </MIME>
            </MIME_INFO>
        </ARTICLE>
    </T_NEW_CATALOG>
</BMECAT>
```

You see there is one `SUPPLIER_AID` and four times a `<MIME>`-tag. I need only the first and the second (where normal and logo). What is in this case with the `SUPPLIER_AID`? I think the code has to look like:

```
WITH Numbered AS
(
    SELECT LoadedDateTime
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ID
          --,a.query('.') AS SUPPLIER_AID
          ,m.query('.') AS mime
    FROM XMLwithOpenXML AS t
    CROSS APPLY t.XMLData.nodes('BMECAT/T_NEW_CATALOG/ARTICLE/MIME_INFO/MIME') AS A(m)
)
SELECT ID
  --,[SUPPLIER_AID].value('(ARTICLE)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS SUPPLIER_AID
    ,mime.value('(MIME/MIME_TYPE)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS MIME_TYPE
    ,mime.value('(MIME/MIME_SOURCE)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS MIME_SOURCE
    ,mime.value('(MIME/MIME_PURPOSE)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS MIME_PURPOSE
    ,mime.value('(MIME/MIME_ORDER)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS MIME_ORDER
FROM Numbered
```

With the new code, I get this:

```
+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
|MIME_TYPE  |MIME_SOURCE   |MIME_PURPOSE |MIME_ORDER |
+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
|image/jpeg |ube105252.jpg |normal       |1          |
+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
|image/jpeg |bbd372670.jpg |logo         |2          |
+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
|image/jpeg |ube105252.jpg |logo         |3          |
+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
|image/jpeg |bbd372670.jpg |others       |4          |
+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
|image/jpeg |bbd372670.jpg |others       |5          |
+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
```

But what I need is something like:

```
+-------------+------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
|SUPPLIER_AID | MIME_TYPE  |    MIME_SOURCE   | MIME_PURPOSE |  MIME_ORDER |
+-------------+------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
|9900026005   | image/jpeg |    ube105252.jpg | normal       |  1          |
+-------------+------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
|9900026005   | image/jpeg |    bbd372670.jpg | logo         |  2          |
+-------------+------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Hi, see my update...

Comment: Btw: Next time place a comment with `@Shnugo` below my answer. I came back just by incidence, had not seen this otherwise...

Comment: Oh. Of cause. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach with `FROM OPENXML` is outdated and should not be used any more. There are much better XML methods like `.node()`, `.value()`, `.query()` and `.modify()`.

The way you get the XML into your table is quite OK. Once you have it there, you should continue like this:

**Attention** I use a declared *mock-up-table* to simulate your table.

```
DECLARE @XMLwithOpenXML TABLE(XMLData XML,LoadedDateTime DATETIME);

INSERT INTO @XMLwithOpenXML VALUES
('<MIME_INFO>
    <MIME>
        <MIME_TYPE>image/jpeg</MIME_TYPE>
        <MIME_SOURCE>ube105252.jpg</MIME_SOURCE>
        <MIME_PURPOSE>normal</MIME_PURPOSE>
        <MIME_ORDER>1</MIME_ORDER>
    </MIME>
    <MIME>
        <MIME_TYPE>image/jpeg</MIME_TYPE>
        <MIME_SOURCE>bbd372670.jpg</MIME_SOURCE>
        <MIME_PURPOSE>logo</MIME_PURPOSE>
        <MIME_ORDER>2</MIME_ORDER>
    </MIME>
</MIME_INFO>',GETDATE());
```

At this point, your XML is successfully taken into your table

The CTE "Numbered" will read all `MIME` elements using `.nodes()` in there inherent order and number them accordingly.

The `SELECT` pulls the actual data

```
WITH Numbered AS
(
    SELECT LoadedDateTime
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ID
          ,m.query('.') AS mime
    FROM @XMLwithOpenXML AS t
    CROSS APPLY t.XMLData.nodes('/MIME_INFO/MIME') AS A(m)
)
SELECT ID
      ,LoadedDateTime
      ,mime.value('(MIME/MIME_TYPE)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS MIME_TYPE
      ,mime.value('(MIME/MIME_SOURCE)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS MIME_SOURCE
      ,mime.value('(MIME/MIME_PURPOSE)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS MIME_PURPOSE
      ,mime.value('(MIME/MIME_ORDER)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS MIME_ORDER
FROM Numbered
```

The result

```
+----+-------------------------+------------+---------------+--------------+------------+
| ID | LoadedDateTime          | MIME_TYPE  | MIME_SOURCE   | MIME_PURPOSE | MIME_ORDER |
+----+-------------------------+------------+---------------+--------------+------------+
| 1  | 2016-09-15 16:37:30.730 | image/jpeg | ube105252.jpg | normal       | 1          |
+----+-------------------------+------------+---------------+--------------+------------+
| 2  | 2016-09-15 16:37:30.730 | image/jpeg | bbd372670.jpg | logo         | 2          |
+----+-------------------------+------------+---------------+--------------+------------+
```

### UPDATE

You did not show the full XML... With the example given above this code extracts all you might want to knwo:

```
WITH Numbered AS
(
    SELECT Id
          ,LoadedDateTime
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS MimeRowNr
          ,a.value('@mode','nvarchar(max)') ARTICLE_MODE
          ,a.value('SUPPLIER_AID[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS SUPPLIER_AID
          ,m.query('.') AS mime
    FROM XMLwithOpenXML AS t
    CROSS APPLY t.XMLData.nodes('/BMECAT/T_NEW_CATALOG/ARTICLE') AS A(a)
    CROSS APPLY a.nodes('MIME_INFO/MIME') AS B(m)
)
SELECT Id
      ,MimeRowNr
      ,LoadedDateTime
      ,ARTICLE_MODE
      ,SUPPLIER_AID
      ,mime.value('(MIME/MIME_TYPE)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS MIME_TYPE
      ,mime.value('(MIME/MIME_SOURCE)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS MIME_SOURCE
      ,mime.value('(MIME/MIME_PURPOSE)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS MIME_PURPOSE
      ,mime.value('(MIME/MIME_ORDER)[1]','int') AS MIME_ORDER
FROM Numbered;
```

The result

```
+----+-----------+-------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------+------------+
| Id | MimeRowNr | LoadedDateTime          | ARTICLE_MODE | SUPPLIER_AID | MIME_TYPE       | MIME_SOURCE   | MIME_PURPOSE | MIME_ORDER |
+----+-----------+-------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------+------------+
| 1  | 1         | 2016-09-16 09:32:53.570 | new          | 9900026005   | image/jpeg      | ube105252.jpg | normal       | 1          |
+----+-----------+-------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------+------------+
| 1  | 2         | 2016-09-16 09:32:53.570 | new          | 9900026005   | image/jpeg      | bbd372670.jpg | logo         | 2          |
+----+-----------+-------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------+------------+
| 1  | 3         | 2016-09-16 09:32:53.570 | new          | 9900026005   | image/jpeg      | ube305149.jpg | logo         | 3          |
+----+-----------+-------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------+------------+
| 1  | 4         | 2016-09-16 09:32:53.570 | new          | 9900026005   | image/jpeg      | ube108453.jpg | others       | 4          |
+----+-----------+-------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------+------------+
| 1  | 5         | 2016-09-16 09:32:53.570 | new          | 9900026005   | application/pdf | ube007100.pdf | others       | 5          |
+----+-----------+-------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------+------------+
```

Comment: Hello again. What have I to do, when in this examble all tags inside the <MIME_INFO> have the same names? I mean <MIME_TYPE> is only <MIME>, <MIME_SOURCE> is only <MIME> and so on... Because in my XML is also a tag <ARTICLE_DEATILS> and inside there are many tags with the same Name --> <KEYWORD>

Comment: Please avoid chameleon questions... This issue is solved and closed. Please start a new question, something like *How can I retrieve data from XML if all elements have the same name?*, poste a (reduced but complete) tree and place a comment here with a link. I'll pop up there soon :-)

Comment: I did it with --> How can I retrieve data from XML if all elements have the same name? THX.